# How to log out from AWS Cognito in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to implement authentication using AWS Cognito in a ASP.NET Core 5 web app.

I can get authenticated, but now I want to implement a logout function.

I can kind of get the logout to work, in that ASP.NET thinks I'm not authenticated.

In my Startup.cs I have:

```
options.SignedOutRedirectUri = Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:SignedOutRedirectUri"];

options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
{
    OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = context =>
    {
        var logoutUri = options.SignedOutRedirectUri;
        context.Response.Redirect(logoutUri);
        context.HandleResponse();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};
```

In my appsettings.json I have:

```
  "SignedOutRedirectUri": "https://mydomain.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/logout?client_id=<<clientid>>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44306/Home/LoggedOut"
```

In my Logout controller, I have:

```
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        return Redirect("/Home/LoggedOut");
```

So when I click my Logout link, I am redirected to /Home/LoggedOut and I am no longer authenticated (in that User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = false).

But when I go to any page with [Authorize] on it, it automatically re-authenticates me to the same user I was logged in as - it never gives me a chance to log in as a different user. I want it to take me to the Cognito login dialog and ask me to authenticate again. So it looks like something is not getting cleared somewhere, I suppose on the AWS Cognito side of things.

Why isn't this sending me back to the login dialog to re-authenticate? I thought a GET to the AWS /logout endpoint was supposed to that.

Comment: Did you figure out what the problem was? I'm having the same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is the parameters of the URL you are constructing for AWS Logout endpoint. (you haven't set logout_uri)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html example 1 shows the required parameters to logout and redirect back to the client.

Here is how I've done it.

```
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
{
    OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = context =>
    {
        context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = 
           GetAbsoluteUri(Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:EndSessionEndPoint"], Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:Authority"]);
        context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("client_id", Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:ClientId"]);
        context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("logout_uri", "https://localhost:5001");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};
```

The logout_uri must match exactly the configured signout url on AWS app client settings.

Helper method

```
 private string GetAbsoluteUri(string signoutUri, string authority)
        {
            var signOutUri = new Uri(signoutUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            var authorityUri = new Uri(authority, UriKind.Absolute);

            var uri = signOutUri.IsAbsoluteUri ? signOutUri : new Uri(authorityUri, signOutUri);
            return uri.AbsoluteUri;
        }
```

Logging out is done with the two lines below. As you worked out, the first line is logging you out locally by clearing out the local authentication cookie, the second line ordinarily would call off to an end_session endpoint on your IDP to log out of your IDP, however as cognito doesn't have and end_session endpoint, you override that when you configure the middleware via OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut event, instructing it instead to call off to the logout endpoint that cognito does have, and that's where this URL is used. Since you hadn't constructed that correctly it never logs out of cognito.

```
public async Task Logout()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
```

and the configuration values

```
...
"EndSessionEndPoint": "logout",
"ClientId": "<your client id>",
"Authority": "https://<your domain>.auth.<your region>.amazoncognito.com"
...
```

hopefully that helps.